# jQuery Mobile: Function returns wrong DIV id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have something like this on a page:

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page" data-theme="a">Page 1</div>            
<div id="page2" data-role="page" data-theme="a">Page 2</div>            
<div id="page3" data-role="page" data-theme="a">Page 3</div>
<div id="page4" data-role="page" data-theme="a">Page 4</div>
```

and the script that handles a swipeleft event is:

```
var pages = ["page1","page2","page3","page4"];

for( var i=0; i<pages.length; i++  ) {
    var thisPage = '#'+pages[i];

    if( i < pages.length-1) {
        $(thisPage).on('swipeleft', function() {
            var nextPage = '#'+(pages[i+1]);
            console.log(thisPage+'|'+nextPage);
        });
    }
}
```

At this point you should be stuck on Page1 because there is no actual transition happening but if you try doing a swipeleft gesture the log shows this:

```
#page4|#undefined
```

Whereas the expected output should be:

```
#page1|#page2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable (i) is defined in the wrong scope. You can try passing the loop index to a Self-invoking function that closes with that value:

```
var pages = ["page1","page2","page3","page4"];

for( var i=0; i<pages.length; i++  ) {
    if( i < pages.length-1) {
        (function(index){
            var thisPage = '#'+(pages[index]);
            $(thisPage).on('swipeleft', function() {
                var nextPage = '#'+(pages[index+1]);
                console.log(thisPage+'|'+nextPage);
            });
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Just a question though. How will the function know that the parameter "index" is actually the variable "i"?

Comment: You're passing it in the third last line: })(i);

Comment: Great! I thinks it's working although there appears to be a new error saying "TypeError: $(...).on(...) is not a function". Perhaps it's not seeing $thisPage?

Comment: Ok, I just made a bit of typo there. It's working perfectly. Thanks a lot!